# Unable to connect to open stack object storage from java application

Tags: java, openstack, openstack-swift, cloud-storage

I am trying to connect to object storage with JOSS.

Here is my connection code:

```
    AccountConfig config = new AccountConfig();

    config.setUsername(USERNAME);
    config.setPassword(PASSWORD);

    config.setAuthUrl(AUTHURL);
    config.setTenantName(TenantName);

    Account account = new AccountFactory(config).createAccount();
```

However I am getting exceptions as shown below.

Please help me in resolving this issue. Googled alot but not able to find solution. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Note: By giving same credentials, AuthUrl, I was able to connect to open stack object storage from clients like cloudberry.

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE     at
>   org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.core.AbstractCommand.createObjectMapper(AbstractCommand.java:137)
>     at
>   org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.identity.KeystoneAuthenticationCommandImpl.setAuthenticationHeader(KeystoneAuthenticationCommandImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.identity.KeystoneAuthenticationCommandImpl.(KeystoneAuthenticationCommandImpl.java:29)
>     at
>   org.javaswift.joss.command.impl.factory.AuthenticationCommandFactoryImpl.createAuthenticationCommand(AuthenticationCommandFactoryImpl.java:27)
>     at
>   org.javaswift.joss.client.impl.ClientImpl.createAccount(ClientImpl.java:84)
>     at
>   org.javaswift.joss.client.impl.ClientImpl.createAccount(ClientImpl.java:27)
>     at
>   org.javaswift.joss.client.core.AbstractClient.authenticate(AbstractClient.java:35)
>     at
>   org.javaswift.joss.client.factory.AccountFactory.createAccount(AccountFactory.java:30)
>     at
>   com.intel.vpg.avl.controller.AvlController.reports(AvlController.java:172)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (that works for me) :

```
AccountConfig config = new AccountConfig();
config.setUsername(username);
config.setPassword(password);
config.setAuthUrl(URL);
config.setAuthenticationMethod(AuthenticationMethod.BASIC);
Account account = new AccountFactory(config).createAccount();
Container container = account.getContainer("container-name");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may be cased by maven dependency conflict, check your maven dependency about `org.codehaus.jackson`, then set the united version. I solved this error by this method, Hope it will help you.